# Deleting older rows and replace with the newest one in Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The following SQL query allows me to delete duplicate entries and to re-order with a new ID the rows in my database.

However when deleting duplicate rows I need to KEEP ONLY THE LAST ONE (and delete all older duplicates).

Name, date and time are same among duplicate rows. The only criteria to define the newest row might be its ID or the simple fact that is stored in the database as last row.
How can I modify the code to fix it?

```
 $creatmp = mysql_query("CREATE TABLE tmp AS SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1 GROUP BY name, date, hour, city, province"); 
 $cancmytable = mysql_query("DROP TABLE mytable"); 
 $datmpamytable = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE tmp RENAME TO mytable"); 
 $creareorderid = mysql_query("CREATE TABLE reorderid LIKE mytable");
 $popolareorderid = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reorderid SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY date,hour");
 $emptyfieldid = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `reorderid` DROP `id`");
 $recountone = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `reorderid` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
 $recounttwo = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `reorderid` ADD `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;");
 $emptymytable = mysql_query("DROP TABLE mytable");
 $renamereorderid = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE reorderid RENAME TO mytable");
```

Comment: First of all, you should stop to use `mysql_` functions - they're deprecated and not longer supported in PHP7. You should use `mysqli_*` or `PDO_*` instead.

Comment: yes you're right, but this is an uninfluent point. Of course I will in the definitive code.
Thank you so much, anyway , for your suggestion

Comment: instead of running all that query's , you should loop through your table and inside that loop run another loop and query to check for duplicate and some statements to see which is the latest data and time. then simply delete where it is not the latest. then just drop the primary key and add it again .

Comment: Thanks Gert but i don't know how to do it